# How can I fill vertical tables with PHP/Smarty

Tags: php, html, html-table, smarty

I have this table, and I have a question about it:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>&nbsp;</th>
            <th>mo</th>
            <th>tu</th>
            <th>we</th>
            <th>th</th>
            <th>fr</th>
            <th>sa</th>
            <th>su</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>min. temp</td>
            <td>10</td>
            <td>9</td>
            <td>8</td>
            <td>8</td>
            <td>12</td>
            <td>11</td>
            <td>13</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>max. temp<br></td>
            <td>18</td>
            <td>17</td>
            <td>15</td>
            <td>16</td>
            <td>18</td>
            <td>17</td>
            <td>19</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>weather</td>
            <td>sunny</td>
            <td>rain</td>
            <td>sunny<br></td>
            <td>cloudy</td>
            <td>clear view</td>
            <td>rain</td>
            <td>cloudy</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Now I'm curious how can I fill this table vertically with data. This is a weather-forecast table.

My array is:

```
[0] => Array
        (
            [time] => 1462226400
            [summary] => Lichte regen gedurende de ochtend.
            [icon] => rain
            [sunriseTime] => 1462248380
            [sunsetTime] => 1462302536
             .....
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [time] => 1462312800
            [summary] => Licht bewolkt gedurende de avond.
            [icon] => partly-cloudy-day
            [sunriseTime] => 1462334669
            [sunsetTime] => 1462389037
            .......
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [time] => 1462399200
            [summary] => Licht bewolkt gedurende de nacht.
            [icon] => partly-cloudy-night
            [sunriseTime] => 1462420961
            [sunsetTime] => 1462475538
            ...........
        )
```

Anyone an idea how I can solve this? And how can I solve this in Smarty?

Comment: Please give us an example about how do you want to display the information from your array. I've create a demo with your initial table: https://jsfiddle.net/c21c24zb/. Feel free to extend it.

Comment: Yes, i mean that sample... How can i put each item from my array into a columns?

Answer (score 0):

You can just use javascript for this purpose.

```
array_size = your_array.lenght();
table = document.getElementById('your_table');
for(i=0; array_size<i; i++)
{
   table.innerHtml = "<tr>
      <td>" + your_array[i]['time'] + "</td>
      <td>" + your_array[i]['summary'] + "</td>
      <td>" + your_array[i]['icon'] + "</td>
      <td>" + your_array[i]['sunriseTime'] + "</td>
      <td>" + your_array[i]['sunsetTime'] + "</td>
    </tr>"
}
```

Comment: Thnx, but i use PHP. I want put each item into a column of my table.